# Twitter Bootstrap block layout issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

At the moment I'm working with the (Twitter) Bootstrap framework and having difficulties with the following (responsive)layout:

http://www.dreamix-studio.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_q.jpg

The problem is the image is bigger then the rest. Does anyone know how to get this working?

EDIT Code:

```
   <div class="row-fluid">

       <div class="span6">

           <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span3"><img src="http://www.dreamix-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/icon_3jaar-150x150.png" class="blog-icon2"/></div>

               <div class="span9" ><h2 class="blog-title2">titel</h2>

               <p>Date</p> </div>

               <div class="span12">
               <p>Dit is een lange tekst met beschrijving van de app</p></div>                        
           </div>

       </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: above URl redirect to a 404 page ..have a look

Comment: Thanks Samuel. Changed to the correct URL

Comment: Please provide the html

Comment: (Should have done that.. ok HTML code paste)

Comment: are you using responsive layout

Comment: Using responsive yes.

Comment: there is a structural problem here since since the `span6` row-fluid you have columns `3 + 9 + 12`, in a row you can have max of 12 columns in this case you have 24

Comment: Also because of the responsive nature, you need to increase the width of the result panel in jsfiddle if you want to make the columns work fine http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Y65hu/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
    <head>
        <title>Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.0.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>-->
        <link href=" http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href=" http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body> <div class="row-fluid">

       <div class="span6">

           <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span2"><img src="http://www.dreamix-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/icon_3jaar-150x150.png" class="blog-icon2"/></div>

               <div class="span9" ><h2 class="blog-title2">titel</h2>

               <p>Date</p> </div>

               <div class="span12">
               <p>Dit is een lange tekst met beschrijving van de app</p></div>                        
           </div>

       </div>
       <div class="span6">

           <div class="row-fluid">
               <div class="span2"><img src="http://www.dreamix-studio.com/wp-content/uploads/icon_3jaar-150x150.png" class="blog-icon2"/></div>

               <div class="span9" ><h2 class="blog-title2">titel</h2>

               <p>Date</p> </div>

               <div class="span12">
               <p>Dit is een lange tekst met beschrijving van de app</p></div>                        
           </div>

       </div>

   </div></body>

</html>
```

Please let me know if your need is satisfied

Comment: Thats it! Awesome work Samuel, big thanks and again sorry for missing the essential stuff in the question!